Error file installing qt 5.15 from qt online installer 4.7.0. Installer says file not found
I am trying to install qt 5.15 from qt online installer but the installer works fine for 99% but in the last bit where it is downloading ninja it just give the following error. I tried changing the mirrors that also did not work. Is there any solution for it? It seams as if they have removed the ninja file from their repos
Cannot download archive https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/qtproject//online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_ninja/qt.tools.ninja/1.10.2-202108061017linux64_ninja.7z: Error transferring https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/qtproject//online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/tools_ninja/qt.tools.ninja/1.10.2-202108061017linux64_ninja.7z.sha1 - server replied: Not Found

